# Ansible - Iterate through array using with items

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

**I do have a simple json file, where i need to pull a set of value from EACH array item, but during iteration it fails.**

My playbook looks like:

```
code:

---

 - name: direct - this works like charm
   set_fact:
     bb: "{{ pr_json.json.issues[0].fields.customfield_11756.value }}"

 - debug:
     var: bb

 - name: via array - this is not working since iteration is not happening
   set_fact:
     dd_branch: "{{ pr_json.json.issues[{{ item }}].fields.customfield_11756.value }}"
   register: mass

 - debug:
     var: mass
```

Getting output as:

```
TASK [jira_update : direct - this works like charm] ********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/test/ansible_jira/roles/jira_update/tasks/call.yml:3
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "bb": "R4.19"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [jira_update : debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/test/ansible_jira/roles/jira_update/tasks/call.yml:7
ok: [localhost] => {
    "bb": "R4.19"
}

TASK [jira_update : via array - this is not working since iteratoin is not happening] **********************************************************************************
task path: /home/test/ansible_jira/roles/jira_update/tasks/call.yml:10
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ pr_json.json.issues[{{ item }}].fields.customfield_11756.value }}"
}
```

Please do let us know how can I iterate through an array variable value on every sequence.

tried this too, but can somebody help to iterate the array values, please.

```
 - name: Create PR request in TEMS JIRA
   jira:
     uri: "{{ tems_jira }}"
     username: "{{ user }}"
     password: "{{ pass }}"
     operation: create
     project: PR
     issuetype: 'PR-Form'
     summary: "{{ pr_json.json| json_query('issues[].fields.summary') }}"
     description: "{{ pr_json.json | json_query('issues[].fields.description') }}"
   args:
     fields:
       customfield_10303:
         value: "{{ pr_json.json | json_query('issues[].fields.customfield_11756.value') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Youy need to feed your list into a with_items iterator.  Thats what sets the item variable for looping purposes.

```
- name: via array - this is not working since iteration is not happening
  set_fact:
    dd_branch: "{{ pr_json.json.issues[ item ].fields.customfield_11756.value }}"
  register: mass
  with_items:
    - 0
    - 1
```

That will iterate through all of the list items of pr_json.json.issues which will let you dive deeper into the variable structure like you are looking for.  There are a lot of other factors that you can feed into the loop that might interest you that you can find detailed here.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: issues is an array for me, i need something like 
pr_json.json.issues[0].fields.customfield_11756.value
pr_json.json.issues[1].fields.customfield_11756.value

here I need the iteration of 0 & 1 whose values are inside the ARRAY. 

Normal iterations would work as you said, but this doesn't

Comment: Ok, if you need to iterate through 0 and 1 specifically, then you can just use those as a list, and then iterate through those.  I will edit my answer to show this.  If 0 and 1 are not always defined, then you can add an additional when clause for when one or the other isn't defined.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the one which you have shared is already tried and question has been raise for the same :D :D. this is not working and throwing the error as - "fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ pr_json.json.issues[{{ item }}].fields.customfield_11756.value }}"

Further help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I made an adjustment to the solution.  I think the extra set of curly brackets surrounding item are not required.  Give that a shot and let me know if it works.